# Поиск строки с переносом

Tags: linux

У меня есть логи, в которых хранится ID объекта, но он в разных меcтах название ID переносится на новую строку

Например:

```bash
adfksdhg123a3213
2ejj

adfksdhg
123a32132ejj
```

Как мне найти ID `adfksdhg123a32132ejj` в файле игнорируя перенос строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, нам нужно найти строку `foo` в файле `input.txt` без учета возможных переносов в файле.

С помощью [`sed`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sed&category=1&russian=2) сформируем регулярное выражение, добавим после каждого символа строки `foo` опциональный перенос `\n?`:

```bash
echo foo | sed 's/./\0\\n?/g'
```

На выходе получим:

```
f\n?o\n?o\n?
```

Теперь подставляем полученное регулярное выражение в [`grep`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=grep&category=1&russian=2):

```bash
grep -zP "f\n?o\n?o\n?" input.txt
```

Одной командой:

```bash
grep -zP "$(echo foo | sed 's/./\0\\n?/g')" input.txt
```